# What's wrong with this aupreset for AUSampler?

Tags: ios, core-audio

I created [this aupreset](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9613235/aupreset.zip) to be loaded into an AUSampler in iOS. I followed the process outlined [here](http://www.electricpeelsoftware.com/2013/02/22/creating-aupreset-files.html) and used the EPSSampler class for the same post. So, if I run my app in the iOS simulator, on iOS 9, the aupreset loads and I get to play notes. If I run the same app on a device running iOS 6, the preset loads but I get no sound. I have used the same process on simulator and device in the past, but always by filtering the built-in sine wave generator, never with audio samples. Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT** I have no way of testing the app on any device running iOS above 6, at least for now.

**EDIT 2** To clarify further, this is how my project looks in Xcode, so you know that my files are going to the right places – i.e. the audio files are going to the Sounds folder within the app bundle (I double checked, just to be sure).

[image]

**EDIT 3** So, I took the Trombone.aupreset from LoadPresetDemo and manually plugged my audio files into it. Magically, [it worked](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9613235/CircBell.aupreset). So I figured I'd load it into the AUSampler's GUI through AU Lab, and make whatever changes I needed to make it sound right – i.e., increasing the release time. It stopped working. So, i manually tweaked the working copy to roughly match what I needed (the docs on aupresets plists are surprisingly unhelpful) and I'm rolling with it. It would seem that AUSampler is messing up the preset, at least for iOS 6 on device, which, currently, is the only device I have to test on. Insights?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really look that deeply,  but the `file://localhost//Library/Audio/Sounds/C.caf` in your file references looks a little fishy. Mine looks like this `/Users/dave/Library/Audio/Sounds/C6.wav`.  Maybe the `file://` part is throwing it off.

Comment: I tried that too. The aupresets provided with Apple's LoadPresetDemo have the file:// url. The docs say that, whenever AUSampler can't find the files at the given location, it will go through a fixed bunch of directories within the app bundle. Predicting the actual path is nearly impossible, in iOS, and every example of aupresets I found around have pretty much any url for the sample files.

Answer (score 1):

Create a directory in your iOS project named Sounds (just like your image shows) and put your caf files in there. The URLs will be groked by iOS.

Here is a [post](http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/creating-an-aupreset/) that goes into detail.